# Best practices to separate business logic from the Controller to the Model layer with Play framework + Scala + Slick

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework, slick

I am a newbie in using Play framework. I am struggling to design a model with one-to-many and retrieve it using Json. I am using Play 2.6, Scala 2.11 with Slick 3.0.0. I have two tables: `Rack` : `case class RackRow(id: String, produced: Float, currentHour: Long)` and `Gpu`: `case class Gpu(id: String, rackId: String, produced: Float, installedAt: String)`.

One of my previous error was to put the business logic in the Controller layer. So I am moving the business logic to the model. Below is my `RackRepository.scala` where I am using Slick:
case class Rack(id: String, produced: Float, currentHour: String, gpuList: Seq[Gpu])

```
case class RackRow(id: String, produced: Float, currentHour: Long)

case class RackException(message: String) extends Exception(message)

class RackRepository @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, gpuRepository: GpuRepository)
                              (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import profile.api._

  lazy val RackTable = new TableQuery(tag => new RackTable(tag))

  def getProfile: JdbcProfile = profile

  def database: JdbcBackend#DatabaseDef = db

  def create(row: List[RackRow]): Future[Option[Int]] =
    db.run(RackTable ++= row)

  def insert(row: RackRow): Future[Unit] =
    db.run(RackTable += row).map(_ => ())

  def updateProduced(rackId: String, produced: Float): Future[Unit] =
    db.run(RackTable.filter(_.id === rackId).map(r => r.produced).update(produced)).map(_ => ())

  def updateRack(rackId: String, produced: Float, currentHour: Long): Future[Unit] =
    db.run(RackTable.filter(_.id === rackId).map(r => (r.produced, r.currentHour)).update(produced, currentHour)).map(_ => ())

  def updateRackProduced(id: String): Future[Unit] = {
    gpuRepository.getByRack(id).map { seqGpuRow: Seq[GpuRow] =>
      val total: Float = seqGpuRow.map(_.produced).sum
      update(id, Some(total), Some(System.currentTimeMillis))
    }
  }

  def update(rackId: String, produced: Option[Float], currentHour: Option[Long]): Future[Unit] = {
    (produced, currentHour) match {
      case (Some(produced), Some(currentHour)) =>
        db.run(RackTable.filter(_.id === rackId).map(r => (r.produced, r.currentHour)).update(produced, currentHour)).map(_ => ())
      case (Some(produced), None) =>
        db.run(RackTable.filter(_.id === rackId).map(r => r.produced).update(produced)).map(_ => ())
      case (None, Some(currentHour)) =>
        db.run(RackTable.filter(_.id === rackId).map(r => r.currentHour).update(currentHour)).map(_ => ())
      case (None, None) => Future("update not executed.")
    }
  }

  def listAllRacksWithSetup(): Future[Setup] = {
    list().flatMap { seqRackRow: Seq[RackRow] =>
      val futureSeqRackRow: Seq[Future[Rack]] = seqRackRow.map { rackRow: RackRow =>
        gpuRepository.getByRack(rackRow.id).map { seqGpuRow: Seq[GpuRow] =>
          val seqGpu = seqGpuRow.map(gpuRepository.gpuRowToGpu) // return Seq[Gpu]
          Rack(rackRow.id, rackRow.produced, Util.toDate(rackRow.currentHour), seqGpu)
        } // return Future[Rack]
      }
      val futureSeqRack: Future[Seq[Rack]] = Future.sequence(futureSeqRackRow)
      futureSeqRack.map(racks => Setup(getProfitPerGpu, racks))
    }
  }
}
```

If you see the constructor of the class `RackRepository`, I am passing the parameter `gpuRepository: GpuRepository`, that is the other model. I guess this approach is not right. But I did this to use the method `gpuRepository.getByRack()` in the `def listAllRacksWithSetup()`.
The problem comes when I go to the other model `GpuRepository` where I cannot pass `rackRepository: RackRepository` in the constructor because it throws an error about recursive dependency. So, this is why my approach is not right.
How do I design the `RackRepository` and `GpuRepository` to one have access to the other? If this is right based on best practices.

Comment: You can check this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K65Z7wkydPs. Here is explained how you can organize business logic with slick framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess during making the question I realize what is the answer. but thanks to everyone that read my question...
I create a `lazy val rackRepository = new RackRepository(dbConfigProvider)` inside the `GpuRepository`. I wonder if this is still a good practice with Play framework. If someone could still answer about best practices of MVC in Play framework.
Thanks

```
class GpuRepository @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                             (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import profile.api._

  lazy val GpuTable = new TableQuery(tag => new GpuTable(tag))
  lazy val rackRepository = new RackRepository(dbConfigProvider)
```